# Emulating altera bitstream

Tags: fpga, emulation, intel-fpga

I have a compiled (binary) bitstream file which I just want to emulate in software.

Linux, Mac, Windows.. anything goes. I know it will probably take a long time but I don't really care how long it takes. Anyway, I do NOT want to load the code to a real FPGA and run it.

Is there a software that can be used to achieve that goal?

Comment: Not sure, but...one way is to get the FPGA vendor tools to back-annotate and/or generate netlist HDL which you can simulate in a HDL simulator such as Modelsim.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

FPGA simulators only work on HDL code. Once a design has been built into a bitstream, that file can only be used to program an FPGA.

Comment: Is there no way to actually emulate how that FPGA will work using some kind of software, like a virtual machine? (Obviously it will be slower but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work)

Comment: @Nimo No. FPGA manufacturers don't make the necessary tools available, and the bitstream format is proprietary and undocumented (so nobody else can build the tools either).